# If $f$ is $C^2$ function in $L^2$ and $f_{xx},f_{yy}$ in $L^2$, then is bounded a.e??

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is $C^2$ function on in $R^2$ and $f\in$ $L^2(R^2,dxdy)$ and $f_{xx},f_{yy} \in$ $L^2$ . Is $f$ in L^infty??

I can't find counter example. 
If I construct a function s.t second derivative in $L^2$, then $f$ is unbounded and not in $L^2$. how to prove? is related to fourier inversion?(Plancherel)

Comment: edit to more weak condition..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is clear from Plancherel. The hypothesis implies that $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}(1+|\xi|^2)^2|\hat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty.$$Integration in polar coordinates shows that $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}(1+|\xi|^2)^{-2}\,d\xi<\infty,$$so Cauchy-Schwarz implies that $\hat f\in L^1$.